# How would I correctly implement parcel/parcelable in a Hash of objects in Java/Android

Tags: android, object, hash, hashmap, parcel

I have the following classes: Experiment and Measurements. I pass a HashMap containing Experiment objects as a value, and their Experiment.getExperimentName as a key, between Android activities.

These Experiment objects in turn contain a HashMap of Measurements objects. This HashMap has a the Measurements objects as a value, and their Measurements.getMeasurements as a key.

These Measurements objects then contain an ArrayList of doubles.

I've tried many variations of using bundle or directly putting in a parcel, but I keep getting a "ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: nl.bioinf.thema12.labpal.objects.Measurements" when I read the HashMap in the new activity.

How Would I correctly implement parcel/parcelable?

The Experiment Class:

```
package nl.bioinf.thema12.labpal.objects;
import java.util.HashMap;
//import java.util.Set;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * @author roy
 * a class which describes an experiment
 */
public class Experiment implements Parcelable{
    private String experimentName = "";
    private HashMap<String,Measurements> measurements = new HashMap<String,Measurements>();

    //every Experiment needs a name to make it unique
    public Experiment(String experimentName) {
        this.experimentName=experimentName;
    }

    /**
     * a method which adds values to a measurement
     * @param   measurementName the name of the measurement you want to write a value to
     * @param   measurement the value of the measurement you want to add
     * @return  the sequence from the fasta
     */
    public void addValueToMeasurements(String measurementName, double measurement){
        //try to add the measurement
        if(measurements.get(measurementName)== null){
            Measurements m = new Measurements(measurementName);
            m.addMeasurement(measurement);
            measurements.put(measurementName,m);
        }
        //if the measurement does not exist, create it
        else{
            measurements.get(measurementName).addMeasurement(measurement);  
        }
    }
    /**
     * a method which returns the experiment name
     * @return  the experiment name
     */ 
    public String getExperimentName(){
        return experimentName;
    }



    //This makes the object parselable, I don't understand why
    /**
     * a constructor for the parcelable variant of the object
     */     
    public Experiment(Parcel in){
        measurements = new HashMap<String,Measurements>();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * a method which writes the objects to a parcel
     */ 
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //dest.writeString(experimentName);
        //for(String s: (Set<String>)measurements.keySet()){
            //dest.writeString(s);
            //dest.writeValue(measurements.get(s));
        //}
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("experimentName", experimentName);
        b.putSerializable("measurements", measurements);
        dest.writeBundle(b);
    }

    /**
     * a method which reads from a parcel
     */ 
    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in){
        //experimentName = in.readString();
        Bundle b = in.readBundle();
        experimentName = b.getString("experimentName");
        measurements = (HashMap<String, Measurements>)b.getSerializable("measurements");
    }

    /**
     * generic parcelable creator method
     */ 
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public Experiment createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Experiment(in);
            }

            public Experiment[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Experiment[size];
            }
     };


}
```

The Measurements Class

```
package nl.bioinf.thema12.labpal.objects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
/**
 * @author roy
 * a class which describes a group of measurements
 */

public class Measurements implements Parcelable{
    private ArrayList<Double> measurements;
    private String measurementName;

    //each measurement has at least a name and an empty list of measurements
    public Measurements(String measurementName) {
        this.measurementName=measurementName;
        measurements = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

    /**
     * a method which adds a measurement to an ArrayList of measurements
     * @param   measurement a measurement to add to the ArrayList
     */
    public void addMeasurement(double measurement){
        measurements.add(measurement);
        System.out.println("added a measurement");
    }

    /**
     * a method which returns the measurement name
     * @return  the measurement name
     */
    public String getMeasurementName(){
        return measurementName;
    }

    /**
     * a method which returns an ArrayList of the values in the measurement
     * @return  the values of the measurements in an ArrayList
     */
    public ArrayList<Double> getMeasurements(){
        return measurements;
    }

    //This makes the object parselable, I don't understand why
    /**
     * a constructor for the parcelable variant of the object
     */     
    public Measurements(Parcel in){
        measurements = new ArrayList<Double>();
        readFromParcel(in);

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * a method which writes the objects to a parcel
     */ 
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //dest.writeString(measurementName);
        //dest.writeList(measurements);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("measurementName", measurementName);
        b.putSerializable("measurements", measurements);
    }

    /**
     * a method which reads from a parcel
     */ 
    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in){
        //measurementName = in.readString();
        //measurements = in.readArrayList(Object.class.getClassLoader());
        Bundle b = in.readBundle();
        measurementName = b.getString("measurementName");
        measurements = (ArrayList<Double>)b.getSerializable("measurements");
    }

    /**
     * generic parcelable creator method
     */ 
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public Measurements createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Measurements(in);
            }

            public Measurements[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Measurements[size];
            }
     };
}
```

code for the activity that receives the bundle

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //get the intent passed by the other activity
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    experiment = b.getParcelable("nl.bioinf.thema12.labpal.objects.Experiment");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_table);
}
```

code for the activity that sends the bundle

```
//setup the table button
        table = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_activityMain_table);
        table.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                try{
                    Intent intentToPassToShowTable = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTable.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putParcelable("nl.bioinf.thema12.labpal.objects.Experiment", experiments.get(experimentName.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                    intentToPassToShowTable.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(intentToPassToShowTable);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi There Try this code it's working fine

```
  package com.example.objectsharing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Experiment implements Parcelable {
private String experimentName = "";
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> measurements = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>>();

// every Experiment needs a name to make it unique
public Experiment(String experimentName) {
    this.experimentName = experimentName;
}

/**
 * a method which adds values to a measurement
 * 
 * @param measurementName
 *            the name of the measurement you want to write a value to
 * @param measurement
 *            the value of the measurement you want to add
 * @return the sequence from the fasta
 */
public void addValueToMeasurements(String measurementName,
        double measurement) {
    // try to add the measurement
    if (measurements.get(measurementName) == null) {
        // Measurements m = new Measurements(measurementName);
        ArrayList<Double> _data = new ArrayList<Double>();
        // m.addMeasurement(measurement);
        _data.add(measurement);
        measurements.put(measurementName, _data);
    }
    // if the measurement does not exist, create it
    else {
        measurements.get(measurementName).add(measurement);
    }
}

/**
 * a method which returns the experiment name
 * 
 * @return the experiment name
 */
public String getExperimentName() {
    return experimentName;
}

// This makes the object parselable, I don't understand why
/**
 * a constructor for the parcelable variant of the object
 */
public Experiment(Parcel in) {
    measurements = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>>();
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
/**
 * a method which writes the objects to a parcel
 */
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // dest.writeString(experimentName);
    // for(String s: (Set<String>)measurements.keySet()){
    // dest.writeString(s);
    // dest.writeValue(measurements.get(s));
    // }
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("experimentName", experimentName);
    b.putSerializable("measurements", measurements);
    dest.writeBundle(b);
}

/**
 * a method which reads from a parcel
 */
public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    // experimentName = in.readString();
    Bundle b = in.readBundle();
    experimentName = b.getString("experimentName");
    measurements = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>>) b
            .getSerializable("measurements");
}

/**
 * generic parcelable creator method
 */
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Experiment createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Experiment(in);
    }

    public Experiment[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Experiment[size];
    }
};
```

}

Comment: This gives me the following error in Experiment.writeToParcel: "The method putParcelable(String, Parcelable) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
 HashMap<String,Measurements>)"

Comment: Please check the modified answer its working fine. i think this will helps you.

Comment: I have added my methods for sending and receiving the bundle between activities, is there something wrong there?

Comment: wrong with the Measurement class that is not implements with the  parceable you dont write the both that's why it was giving the bad parcel Object exception. now it should work try